# Making the text on a webpage draggable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Heres what i'm trying to do.

1. The user selects text from the page
2. The highlighted text should now be draggable
3. The text is now droped into a droppable
4. Which alerts the text back to us.

Here's the code i'm using to detect selected text.

```
if (!window.x) {
    x = {};
}
x.Selector = {};
x.Selector.getSelected = function() {
    var t = '';
    if (window.getSelection) {
        t = window.getSelection();
    } else if (document.getSelection) {
        t = document.getSelection();
    } else if (document.selection) {
        t = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    return t;
}

$(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
        alert(mytext);
});
```

Everything works fine until here , I tried doing this then.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).bind("mouseup", function() {
        var mytext = x.Selector.getSelected();
    alert(mytext);
    var item=$(mytext);
    $(item).draggable({
            start:function(event,ui){$( "#draggable" ).draggable( "option", "revert", true );},
        stop:function(event,ui){$( "#draggable" ).draggable( "option", "revert", true );}

    });

    $("#droppable").droppable({
        accept: item ,
        drop: function() { alert($('#draggable').text()); }
    });    
});
```

How do it convert the text to draggable , Please help , Any new way to do is much welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting..

```
var item=$(mytext);
```

you cannot select text as DOM element. You should add it to a newly created element such as `<p>`

`$("<p>"+mytext+</p>").appendTo("body").dragable({...}).`

Comment: yup this temporarily solves the issue but occupies the page space.